# There are exactly three $2\times 2$ row reduced matrices $\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}$ such that $a+b+c+d=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ be $2\times 2$ matrix with complex entries,
$$A=\begin{bmatrix} a & b\\ c& d\end{bmatrix}$$
Suppose that $A$ is row reduced and also that $a+b+c+d=0$. Prove that there are exactly three such matrices.

Comment: Since you are new, I want to give some advice about the site: **To get the best possible answers, you should explain what your thoughts on the problem are so far**. That way, people won't tell you things you already know, and they can write answers at an appropriate level; also, people tend to be more willing to help you if you show that you've tried the problem yourself. Also, some would consider your post rude because it is a command ("Prove"), not a request for help, so please consider rewriting it.

Comment: The statement is not true. There are exactly three $2\times2$ row echelon forms $\begin{bmatrix} a & b\\ c& d\end{bmatrix}$ such that $a+b+c+d$, but only one of them is a row-**reduced**.

Answer (score 4):

I have seen this question in Section 1.4, Exercise 6 of *Linear Algebra* by Hoffman & Kunze. I believe both the comment to the original question and the already-existing answer are assuming **row-reduced** is the same as **row-reduced echelon**.

In this text, a matrix is **row-reduced** if:

1. the first non-zero entry in each non-zero row is equal to 1
2. each column of the matrix which contains the leading nonzero entry of some row has all its other entries equal to zero.

With this definition, the three matrices are:

$ \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0\\ 0& 0\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} 1 & -1\\ 0& 0\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0\\ 1& -1\end{bmatrix} $

Comment: Your third matrix is not in RREF form, the zero rows must be at the bottom of the matrix.

Comment: just switch the rows in the third matrix. but then you have a duplicate.

Comment: If you read the question and my answer carefully, you will find that row-reduced form and row-reduced echelon form are not the same. You are talking about row reduced echelon form; the question is asking about matrices in row reduced form. This question is exactly the same as the one in Hoffman & Kunze -- there is no mistake.

Comment: Can you provide your workout? Then it may be very helpful. Are row-reduced echelon and row-reduced same?

Answer (score 2):

According to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_echelon_form. The following criteria must be met:

A matrix is in reduced row echelon form (also called row canonical form) if it satisfies the following conditions.

1. All nonzero rows are above any rows of all zeroes.
2. The leading coefficient of a nonzero row is always strictly to the right of the leading coefficient of the row above it.
3. Every leading coefficient is 1 and is the only nonzero entry in its column.

That means c must be 0. Furthermore a=1 or a=0. 
We can then work on the relation $a+b+c+d=0$.

So let's work this out:

First c=0.

1. a=0 -> Then b = -d. But since nonzero coefficients are strictly to the right of the ones on the previous line (rule 2) this means b=d=0.
2. a=1 -> Then b = -1 - d.
   By requirement three b=0, so d must equal -1. Which violates rule 3
3. a = 1 and d = 0 -> b = - a

This gives two distinct shapes of matrices:

$ \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0\\ 0& 0\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} 1 & -1\\ 0& 0\end{bmatrix} $

Comment: Your second matrix here does not satisfy requirement 3.

Comment: Indeed I overlooked this. I edited the comment

Comment: But now the second matrix does not satisfy the "every leading coefficient is 1" part of requirement 3. Actually I cannot think of one besides your first and third examples here...

Comment: Indeed the first matrix can hardly be considered an example of row reduction. Thus there is only one possible outcome

Comment: The zero matrix is row reduced, satisfies all three criteria. One could argue that no reduction was "done", but that same argument would throw out the other examples, if they're given in already row reduced form. So there are indeed two of the row reduced matrices satisfying $a+b+c+d=0$, the two noted in your post.

Comment: The zero matrix does indeed satisfy the all criteria, it is just not an illuminating example. That is all what I meant